# Firebase value is undefined when it is not supposed to be

Tags: javascript, function, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, undefined

I am working on a firebase project. During testing the

```
return user.val().name;
```

will return an

```
undefined
```

value however the

```
console.log(user.val().name)
```

will return the actual string stored in the .name field. Why is that. Also even if assign the

```
user.val().name
```

to a variable, the variable remains undefined.Please help figure out why this happens. I am printing it to a csv.

Here is my code:

```
var database = firebase.database();
var ref2 = database.ref('information/');

var id;
var name;

ref2.on("value", function (one) {

    one.forEach(function (two) {

        if (typeof two.val().Id !== 'undefined') {
            id = two.val().Id;
            name = program(id); //name undefined

        }
        else {
           id = "";
        }

        csv = name + "," + id +"\n";


    });

    download(csv);

});
};


function program (id) {

var database = firebase.database();
var ref = database.ref("users/" + id + "/");

ref.on('value',function(user){

    if (typeof user.val().name === 'undefined') {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        console.log(user.val().name); //this doesnt show undefined
        return user.val().name; //this shows undefined when appended to a html element

    }
})
}
```

**Note:** In the firebase database, the name value is not null. It has a string added to it.

Comment: How are you displaying  displaying this returned value?

Comment: The returned value is assigned to a var "name". Then I am printing the var name to a csv file.

Comment: May I please see the html that's displaying this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I second with Frank's [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47576193/3025732) on why your function `program()` doesn't work. Because `ref.on('value'...` makes an asynchronous call, `program()` does not wait for the completion of `ref.on` and exists with an `undefined` return value.

What you could instead do is use Promises. Wrap the statements inside your `program()` function within a Promise, and upon completion of the asynchronous call, `resolve` or `reject` based on the result it gives.

Here's your function with Promises:

```
function program(id) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        try {
            var database = firebase.database();
            var ref = database.ref("users/" + id + "/");

            ref.on('value', function (user) {
                if (typeof user.val().name === 'undefined') {
                    resolve(null);
                } else {
                    console.log(user.val().name);
                    resolve(user.val().name);
                }
            })
        } catch (e) {
            reject(e)
        }
    });
}
```

And then, here's how you can read the result:

```
program(id).then(function (result) {
        console.log(result)
        //Do what you want with the result here
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
})
```

Note: You're executing this block in a for-each statement. If you're using Promises, you'd also need to look into how to use Promises inside a loop. For reference, check `Promise.all()`

Comment: Thank. That's a nice idea. I will look into promise. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are trying to use the returned name in the code that calls your `program` function. E.g.

```
var name = program("1234");
console.log(name); // this will print undefined
```

This will not work, since your `program()` is not actually returning name. Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. By the time `program()` exits, the data isn't loaded yet.

This is easiest to see by putting a few log statements into the code:

```
function program (id) {
    var database = firebase.database();
    var ref = database.ref("users/" + id + "/");
    console.log("Before attaching listener");    
    ref.on('value',function(user){
        console.log("Got value from database");
    })
    console.log("After attaching listener, exiting function");    
}
```

This will print:

> Before attaching listener
>
> After attaching listener, exiting function
>
> Got value from database

This is likely not the order that you expected, but it is working as designed. Instead of waiting for the data to be loaded (and making the browser/user wait), your code continues. Then when the data is loaded, your callback is invoked. But in your original code that means that your `return` statement is unable to return the name to the original caller.

This is precisely the reason why the Firebase Database (and most web APIs) use callbacks like the one you pass into `on()`. This callback is invoked when the data is available and is the only place where you can access the user data. So any code that requires the data you just loaded must be **inside** that callback, or be called from inside that callback. E.g.

```
function program (id) {

    var database = firebase.database();
    var ref = database.ref("users/" + id + "/");
    
    ref.on('value',function(user){
    
        if (typeof user.val().name === 'undefined') {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            console.log(user.val().name);
            appendToHtmlElement(user.val().name);
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: I did try this and I figured that I had failed to really explain my problem. I have edited my code to reflect my environment in which the program(id) function is being called.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase> DataBase> Role

Have you changed the value of rules?

[image]

Comment Example!

That can get the value after moving to name.

```
   var ref = database.ref ("users/" + id + "/name");
   ref.on ('value', function (user) {
       if (user.val ()! = null) {
            console.log (user.val ())
        }
   }
```

If not, let's worry about it.

Comment: Yes. The rules are changed to public access (i.e. to what you have showed). It still doesn't work

Comment: Does user.val () return to 'null'? Or Does user.val () return to 'undefined'?

That can get the value after moving to name.

Comment: the user.val() does not return to null. It prints the value of the "name" field. This might be a good move

Answer (score 0):

You should receive the returned value.

```
var name = ref.on('value',function(user){

    if (typeof user.val().name === 'undefined') {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        console.log(user.val().name); //this doesnt show undefined
        return user.val().name; //this shows undefined when appended to a html element

      }
})
```

then use `return name` to get the value. or simply return the `return ref.on('value' ...`

Comment: Can you explain further please. I think I am getting hang of it. More explanation will serve me better. Please