# Variable unchanged and value is undefined inside Firebase callback function

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database, callback

I am working on a firebase project. During testing the

```
return user.val().name;
```

will return an

```
undefined
```

value however the

```
console.log(user.val().name)
```

will return the actual string stored in the .name field. Why is that. Also even if assign the

```
user.val().name
```

to a variable, the variable remains undefined.Please help figure out why this happens. I am printing it to a csv.

Here is my code:

```
var database = firebase.database();
var ref2 = database.ref('information/');

var id;
var name;

ref2.on("value", function (one) {

one.forEach(function (two) {

    if (typeof two.val().Id !== 'undefined') {
        id = two.val().Id;
        name = program(id); //name undefined

    }
    else {
       id = "";
    }

    csv = name + "," + id +"\n";


});

download(csv);

});
};


function program (id) {

var database = firebase.database();
var ref = database.ref("users/" + id + "/");

ref.on('value',function(user){

if (typeof user.val().name === 'undefined') {
    return null;
}
else {
    console.log(user.val().name); //this doesnt show undefined
    return user.val().name; //this shows undefined when returned to the name variable

}
})
}
```

Note: In the firebase database, the name value is not null. It has a string added to it.

Comment: not sure if its the problem but I think you have an extra `}` after download(csv)

Comment: Thank you for the minor fix however the problem remains unsolved

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47566533/4815718