# How to retrieve data from Firebase using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I'm trying to access "id" and store it in a variable. So far the code I have is:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");

ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var childData = childSnapshot.val();
    console.log(childData);
  });
});
```

What I get from above is:

[image]

With that I have access to the object itself, but how can I access the property "id"? I'm reading the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) but I can't figure it out.

Comment: your childData is a javascript object, just do `console.log(childData.id);` or `childData.name` to access the name

Comment: `childData.name` will work but **If data has dynamic key-node in deeper child then `childData.name` will be problematic...!  Working with larg database we should go with key-value approach.**

Comment: did the answer help?

Comment: yes, it did. I selected yours as the answer. Appreciate it. @PeterHaddad

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do this:

```
 var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");

ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
 snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
  var childData = childSnapshot.val();
  var id=childData.id;
  console.log(childData);
 });
});
```

In the above the location is at `users` then you use `on()` method to read data, and using the `forEach` loop, you iterate inside the `pushid` and get the values.

To access each one alone you do this `var ids=childData.id;` or/and `var names=childData.name;`

Also it is better to use `once()` as it only reads data once.

Comment: thank yo so much for this!!!! can you provide the links for the firebase docs for this?

Comment: This is the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write, `foreach` is not written there, can be found here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach @helloworld

Comment: With this example it is returning me an UNDEFINED value

Comment: @FernandoTorres https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47566533/firebase-value-is-undefined-when-it-is-not-supposed-to-be check this. The `on()` method is asynchronous, therefore if you return above you will get an error, you have to return a Promise and then get the value using `then()` callback

Answer (score 2):

You need to get key of parent-node(`L2L6vBsd45DFGfh`) to access `id` child

When you use `push()` method in firebase it will automatic generate unique key for your record.
use `set()` or `update()` method to create your own custom keys.

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    var childData = snapshot.val();
    var key = Object.keys(childData)[0];    //this will return 1st key.         
    console.log(childData[key].id);
});
```

> You will use `for-loop` or `forEach` to get all `keys`.