# multiple markers on google maps from firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-maps-api-3, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Geolocation</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <!-- Place this inside the HTML head; don't use async defer for now -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/geofire/4.1.2/geofire.min.js"></script>

  <script>
        
        var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCWZjRe2CK8Hu2VN35AgZOQ7lQZKcI-UWM",
    authDomain: "carrier-35d7c.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://carrier-35d7c.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "carrier-35d7c",
    storageBucket: "carrier-35d7c.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "827792028763"
  };
        if (!firebase.apps.length) {
            firebase.initializeApp(config);
        }
        
        //Create a node at firebase location to add locations as child keys
        var locationsRef = firebase.database().ref("locations");
        
        // Create a new GeoFire key under users Firebase location
        var geoFire = new GeoFire(locationsRef.push());
      </script>


  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      // Note: This example requires that you consent to location sharing when
      // prompted by your browser. If you see the error "The Geolocation service
      // failed.", it means you probably did not give permission for the browser to
      // locate you.
      var map, infoWindow;
      var lat, lng;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 18
        });
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            lat = position.coords.latitude;
            lng = position.coords.longitude;
            var pos = {lat: lat, lng: lng };
                _setGeoFire();
              var locationsRef = firebase.database().ref("locations");
locationsRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); // declaration 
var data = snapshot.val();
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: {
    lat: data.lat,
    lng: data.lng
  },
  map: map
});
bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
marker.addListener('click', (function(data) {
  return function(e) {
    infowindow.setContent(data.name + "<br>" + this.getPosition().toUrlValue(6) + "<br>" + data.message);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  }
}(data)));
map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
          
            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
            infoWindow.open(map);
            map.setCenter(pos);
          }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
          });
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }
      }
      function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                              'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                              'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
        infoWindow.open(map);
      }
      function _setGeoFire(){
    geoFire.set("User", [lat, lng]).then(()=>{
            console.log("Location added");
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
    </script>
    <script 
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD2nPlSt_nM7PSKD8So8anbUbBYICFWcCA&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I need some help plotting multiple coordinate points from my firebase real-time database on a google map. I'm using geofire to sync the user's current location to the database. Another stack overflow user gave me some code to use and I put it in my program but for some reason, It works for them but does not work for me. [How To Display Multiple Markers Coordinates Stored In Firebase Database On Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49641049/how-to-display-multiple-markers-coordinates-stored-in-firebase-database-on-googl?noredirect=1#comment86380949_49641049). That's the link to the question I asked a couple weeks ago. If anyone could help me figure out why this is not working, I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You now have multiple positions in your data.

The code works if you change it to read the data format in your database.  You have your coordinates in an array named `l` in the `User` object.

```
locationsRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  var data = snapshot.val();
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: data.User.l[0],
      lng: data.User.l[1]
    },
    map: map
  });
  bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
  marker.addListener('click', (function(data) {
    return function(e) {
      infowindow.setContent(this.getPosition().toUrlValue(6) + "<br>" + data.User.g);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    }
  }(data)));
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/fnygnokw/6/)

[image]
**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCWZjRe2CK8Hu2VN35AgZOQ7lQZKcI-UWM",
    authDomain: "carrier-35d7c.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://carrier-35d7c.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "carrier-35d7c",
    storageBucket: "carrier-35d7c.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "827792028763"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  //Create a node at firebase location to add locations as child keys
  var locationsRef = firebase.database().ref("locations");
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  locationsRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot)
    var data = snapshot.val();
    console.log(data);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: data.User.l[0],
        lng: data.User.l[1]
      },
      map: map
    });
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
    marker.addListener('click', (function(data) {
      return function(e) {
        infowindow.setContent(this.getPosition().toUrlValue(6) + "<br>" + data.User.g);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
      }
    }(data)));
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/geofire/4.1.2/geofire.min.js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```