# Adding all marker fetched from Firebase database

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firebase, google-maps-markers

After fetching a list of lat/lon locations from Firebase, I'm able to add a marker for the last user, but I want to add all markers, from all users fetched.

[Lat Lng fetched from firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pS0go.png)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("driversAvailable");
  rootRef.on("child_added",snap=>{
    var lat = snap.child("l").child("0").val();
    var lng = snap.child("l").child("1").val();
    console.log(name,phone);

    $('ol').append( '<li>' + lat +" : " + lng + '</li>' );

    var uluru = {lat: lat, lng: lng};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 15,
      center: karachi
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: uluru,
      map: map
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [multiple markers on google maps from firebase database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49991047/multiple-markers-on-google-maps-from-firebase-database)

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new map instance for each location, that's why you only see the last marker, it was added to a new map.

Just move the map creation outside the listener, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 15,
        center: karachi
    });
    var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("driversAvailable");
    rootRef.on("child_added",snap=>{
        var lat = snap.child("l").child("0").val();
        var lng = snap.child("l").child("1").val();
        console.log(name,phone);

        $('ol').append( '<li>' + lat +" : " + lng + '</li>' );

        var uluru = {lat: lat, lng: lng};
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: uluru,
            map: map
        });
    });
});
```