# set info content value with value from firebase real time database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-maps-api-3, geofire

A stack overflow user gave me an answer to a previous question I had.

He made a fiddle for my answer. His fiddle works perfectly for what I want but for some reason, I can't get his code to work with mine

This is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/fnygnokw/6/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=fnygnokw

This is my code. I want to be able to click on the marker and have it display some information from my database which is what his code is able to do perfectly.

This is the link to the previous question
[multiple markers on google maps from firebase database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49991047/multiple-markers-on-google-maps-from-firebase-database?noredirect=1&lq=1)

If anyone could help me figure out how he was able to do it, I would really appreciate it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Geolocation</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <!-- Place this inside the HTML head; don't use async defer for now -->

    
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/geofire/4.1.2/geofire.min.js"></script>

  <script>
        
        var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "carrier-35d7c.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://carrier-35d7c.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "carrier-35d7c",
    storageBucket: "carrier-35d7c.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "827792028763"
  };
        if (!firebase.apps.length) {
            firebase.initializeApp(config);
        }
        
        //Create a node at firebase location to add locations as child keys
        //var locationsRef = firebase.database().ref("locations");
        
        // Create a new GeoFire key under users Firebase location
        //var geoFire = new GeoFire(locationsRef.push());
        //Create a node at firebase location to add locations as child keys
        //confirm(firebase.auth().currentUser)
    
    //var a = localStorage.getItem('phoneNumber');
    
 
        var locationsRef = firebase.database().ref("locations");
        var pushRef = locationsRef.push()
      // Create a new GeoFire key under users Firebase location
      // replace var geoFire = new GeoFire(locationsRef.push()); with
      var geoFire = new GeoFire(pushRef); 
      </script>


  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      
    
      // Note: This example requires that you consent to location sharing when
      // prompted by your browser. If you see the error "The Geolocation service
      // failed.", it means you probably did not give permission for the browser to
      // locate you.
      var map, infoWindow;
      var lat, lng;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 18
          //mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            lat = position.coords.latitude;
            lng = position.coords.longitude;
            
            var pos = {lat: lat, lng: lng, name };
                _setGeoFire();
              var locationsRef = firebase.database().ref("locations");
locationsRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  var data = snapshot.val();
 
   
   
  
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: data.User.l[0],
      lng: data.User.l[1]
     
    },
    map: map,
     
      
   // new google.maps.Size(42, 68)
  });
  
  
  bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
  marker.addListener('click', (function(data) {
    return function(e) {
      infowindow.setContent(this.getPosition().toUrlValue(6) + "<br>" + data.User.g);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    }
  }(data)));
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
          
            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent('Current Location');
            infoWindow.open(map);
            map.setCenter(pos);
          }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
          });
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }
      }
      function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                              'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                              'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
        infoWindow.open(map);
      }
     function _setGeoFire(){
geoFire.set("User", [lat, lng] ).then(()=>{
  console.log("Location added");
  
  pushRef.child("User").onDisconnect().remove();
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
}
    </script>
    <script 
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD2nPlSt_nM7PSKD8So8anbUbBYICFWcCA&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L41Kp.png)

Comment: I get javascript errors with the posted code (`Uncaught ReferenceError: infowindow is not defined`, your `InfoWindow` object is `infoWindow` not `infowindow`, javascript is case sensitive).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying, could you edit my code to reflect your comment. Also, how were you able to get the markers in your fiddle to be clicked in and show the the coordinates and a value from the database? I have been trying to figure that out

Comment: What do you see in the javascript console when you run the code you posted?

Comment: I edited my post to include a screenshot of my console when I run the code I posted

Comment: If it's possible, could you edit the code I posted to reflect the results of the code on your fiddle? I've been trying for ages but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Note that screenshots are frowned upon, they are not searchable, the text would be better.  You don't think defining bounds would be useful (or changing the code to remove its use)? (forgot I had to fix that error as well as the infowindow error).

Comment: After I fixed these errors, the code shows no errors and works exactly like your fiddle! Thanks again