# Using Google Maps API with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore

Image of Firebase database.

[image: Screen Shot]

This is my Firebase database. The data in there are pictures with Geolocation tags. I want to be able to have the location where each picture was taken pop up on Google Maps using the Google Map API on my website.

I did some research and it looks like the only thing Firebase has in relation to this is creating heat maps. I tried following through and this is what I was able to come up with:

```
 var map, infoWindow, db;
         function initMap() {
           map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
             center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
             zoom: 6
           });
           infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

           // Try HTML5 geolocation.
           db =firebase.firestore();
          // if (navigator.geolocation)
           if(db.collection("signs").where("type", "==", 'geopoint')) {
             navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
               var pos = {
                 lat: position.coords.latitude,
                 lng: position.coords.longitude
               };

               infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
               infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
               infoWindow.open(map);
               map.setCenter(pos);
             }, function() {
               handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
             });
           } else {
             // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
             handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
           }
         }

         function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
           infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
           infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                                 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                                 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
           infoWindow.open(map);
         }
       </script>
       <script async defer
       src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&callback=initMap">
       </script>
```

Comment: related question:[How To Display Multiple Markers Coordinates Stored In Firebase Database On Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49641049/how-to-display-multiple-markers-coordinates-stored-in-firebase-database-on-googl)