# How to display markers from firestore using JS?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to display markers from Firestore, but nothing happens. 
Every solution that I found had coordinates stored like this so I think that the problem might be in the marker position in my code, but I don't know how to fix it.

[image]

This is what my Firestore looks like
[image: https://gyazo.com/1e8ce3184c787cc6fb3aea1a99e7b9f6]

and my code for displaying markers.

```
function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(58.2600006, 22.5297743);
        var myOptions = {disableDefaultUI: true, zoom: 9, center: latlng, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
        firebase.firestore().collection('markers').get().then((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
                console.log(child);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: {lat: parseFloat(child.lat), lng: parseFloat(child.lng)},
                    map: map,
                });
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the code you use to create the Firestore documents? Why do you use a string like `LatLng(58...)` for document ID?

Comment: Can you share what's getting on your console for (console.log(child) ) ? Do you loaded correctly the [Google API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Display Multiple Markers Coordinates Stored In Firebase Database On Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49641049/how-to-display-multiple-markers-coordinates-stored-in-firebase-database-on-googl)

Comment: possible duplicate of [multiple markers on google maps from firebase database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49991047/multiple-markers-on-google-maps-from-firebase-database)

Comment: About the document ID, I'm using multiple applications with one Firebase project and I think it was necessary and for what my console shows: https://gyazo.com/090a03a71125a44408a6ecab92ecb5f5

Comment: [This page](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/firebase) from the documentation shows how to load firebase data onto a map (but no markers)